# Aggregate record counts over a date dimension table considering a secondary date in the aggreation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three tables, one tracks a case, one tracks when a case is closed and the last is a custom table just containing dates for a range of time. I'm a bit lost as to how to create the query for this due to having to populate for each day and factor in the secondary date table.

tblCase:

- tblCase.CaseId [UniqueIdentifier]
- tblCase.CreatedOn [DateTime]

tblCaseClose:

- tblCaseClose.CaseId [UniqueIdentifier]
- tblCaseClose.CreatedOn
  [DateTime]

tblDates:

- tblDates.Date [DateTime]

For each date in tblDates, I'd like to sum the total number of open cases. A case is considered open from its CreatedOn date until a corresponding tblCaseClose record is created related to the case. If a case is created on the same day it is closed, it will count as 0.

Any suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What value does `tblCaseClose.CreatedOn` represent?  The date the case was opened, or the date the case was closed?  Sample table data, expected results, and any query you've got so far (even if it isn't working) is always preferred for any question.

Comment: tblCaseClose.CreatedOn is the date the case was closed. I am simplifying the table structure for the purpose of the question. I didn't share the query as I have not been able to get it working at all and worried it might confuse the question more than explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an inefficient method, but it should work fine on smaller data:

```
select d.*,
       ((select count(*) from tblCase c where c.CreatedOn <= d.date) -
        (select count(*) from tblCaseClose cc where cc.CreatedOn <= d.date)
       ) as NumOpenCases
from tblDates d;
```

In other words, the number of open cases on a given date is the total number of cases that have been opened up to that date minus the number that have been closed.

Unfortunately, SQL Server 2008 doesn't support cumulative sums.  There are more efficient approaches in SQL Server 2012+ using that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a solution I think, I don't know how elegant it is. It does use the idea of subtracting open cases minus closed cases but it ensure generic case closures do not affect the count, only closures on cases included in the result set.

```
DECLARE
@StartDate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()) ,
@EndDate DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT
    tt.Date ,
    ( SUM(tt.[Case Open]) - SUM(tt.[Case Closed]) ) [Open Cases]
FROM
    (
      SELECT
        dateTbl.[Date] ,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(fi.createdon, 0) = 0 THEN 0
             ELSE 1
        END [Case Open] ,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(fir.createdon, 0) != 0
                  AND dateTbl.[Date] >= CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, fir.createdon))) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END [Case Closed]
      FROM
        (
          SELECT
            DATEADD(DAY, Nbr - 1, @StartDate) [Date]
          FROM
            (
              SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY c.object_id) AS Nbr FROM sys.columns c
            ) nbrs
          WHERE
            Nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
        ) dateTbl
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FilteredIncident AS fi ON CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, fi.createdon))) <= dateTbl.[Date]
                                                AND fi.createdon >= @StartDate
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FilteredIncidentResolution AS fir ON fir.incidentid = fi.incidentid
    ) tt
GROUP BY
    tt.[Date]
ORDER BY
    tt.[Date]
```